# Xamarin Android Gallary Photo Stream has null base

Tags: c#, android-intent, xamarin.android, inputstream, memorystream

I am trying to get an image from the gallery and then get the bytes from that image. The concept works for PDFs and Videos though with images the stream I get BaseInputStream is null and therefore errors when trying to copy to a memory stream (I believe), I have tried different intents and setting the position to 0 before copying but to no prevail. All the related code is below.

Creating the Intent

```
    public const int GalleryPhoto = 4;
    public const int GalleryVideo = 5;
    public const int SelectFile = 7;

void IDevice.GetImageFromGallery()
    {
        if (_dir == null)
        { CreateDirectoryForPictures(); }
        Intent imageIntent = new Intent();
        imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
        imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        MyApp.Droid.MainActivity.Main.StartActivityForResult(imageIntent, GalleryPhoto);
    }

    void IDevice.SelectFile()
    {
        if (_dir == null)
        { CreateDirectoryForPictures(); }
        Intent imageIntent = new Intent();
        imageIntent.SetType("application/pdf");
        imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
        MyApp.Droid.MainActivity.Main.StartActivityForResult(imageIntent, SelectFile);
    }

    void IDevice.GetVideoFromGallery()
    {
        if (_dir == null)
        { CreateDirectoryForPictures(); }
        Intent imageIntent = new Intent();
        imageIntent.SetType("video/*");
        imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        MyApp.Droid.MainActivity.Main.StartActivityForResult(imageIntent, GalleryVideo);
    }
```

OnActivityResult in MainActivity.cs

```
  protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {

                if (requestCode == AndroidDevice.GalleryPhoto)
                {
                    selectedFile = data.Data;
                    System.IO.Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data);
                    AndroidDevice._stream = stream;
                    AndroidDevice.ImageHasBeenTaken();
                }
                else if (requestCode == AndroidDevice.GalleryVideo)
                {
                    selectedFile = data.Data;
                    System.IO.Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data);
                    AndroidDevice._stream = stream;
                    AndroidDevice.VideoHasBeenTaken();
                }
                else if (requestCode == AndroidDevice.SelectFile)
                {
                    selectedFile = data.Data;
                    System.IO.Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data);
                    AndroidDevice._stream = stream;
                    AndroidDevice.FileHasBeenSelected();

                }
            }
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

I keep the stream with an object and use it to display the image if it is an image I have picked, and I then use it to get the bytes to upload.

Displaying the image works fine from the stream

`this.ImageObj.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(()=>stream);`

I then have a nice and simple method of getting the bytes from the stream

```
public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
        try
        {                
            if (stream!= null)
            {
                MemoryStream ms  = new MemoryStream();
                stream.CopyTo(ms);
                bytes = ms.ToArray();                  
            }
            return bytes;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Screens.DisplayExcpetion de = new Screens.DisplayExcpetion(ex);
            return bytes;
        }
    }
```

This works for the PDFs and the video though when I select an image I get the following error

> {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.   at Android.Runtime.InputStreamInvoker.Read
>   (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count)
>   [0x00006] in :0    at
>   System.IO.Stream.InternalCopyTo (System.IO.Stream destination,
>   System.Int32 bufferSize) [0x00015] in
>   <05f5f767747c4c30800c25866dc4cdd4>:0    at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo
>   (System.IO.Stream destination) [0x00099] in
>   <05f5f767747c4c30800c25866dc4cdd4>:0    at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Stream:CopyTo (System.IO.Stream)
>   at DAFCheckMobile_DEV.Controls.CTLUploadImage.GetBytes () [0x0001d] in
>   E:\Data\Solutions\DAF\DAFcheckMobile\DAFcheckMobile_DEV\DAFCheckMobile_DEV\DAFCheckMobile_DEV\Controls\CTLUploadImage.cs:325
>   }

The only thing I have noticed about the stream that is different is that
stream.BaseInputStream is null.

I have searched high an low for an answer to this, though there are similar questions I can't find anyone with the same issue or a solution that works.

I am debugging this on a Samsung SM-G920F (Android 7.0 - API 24)

Any help would be much appreciated, I have been banging my head against the wall for a while on this one, sorry if the post is overly long winded.

Answer (score 0):

Using the stream to get an image source appears to be what caused the BaseInputStream to become null, getting the bytes first and then an image source from those bytes resolved the issue.